# In Elder Sign, why do multiple locks have to be resolved in order?

Tags: elder-sign

The [rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Elder%20Sign/support/SL05_ES_Revised_Rulebook.pdf) on page 12 say

> For example, if there are two effects in play that lock the yellow die, the locks are addressed in the order in which they came into play: after the yellow die is freed from the first lock, it is placed on the second lock. After the die is freed from the second lock, the players may add it to their dice pool after using a common item that adds the yellow die to the pool.

This implies to me that two separate adventures that lock the yellow die must be resolved in order of appearance, but I'm skeptical that they mean to say we cannot simply resolve the second adventure first. Is there another way to interpret this rule as described?

Answer (score 2):

I've always taken this rule to mean that the die would go to the next lock in order of appearance. I've assumed that if you resolved the other adventures/monsters that would lock the die, they would just disappear.

There is also [this](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Elder%20Sign/support/SL05-faq-web.pdf) FAQ on Fantasy Flight Games website where they don't even mention this "order" rule.

Comment: It just seems arbitrary which lock the die actually resides on since basically the presence of any yellow lock means the die is locked, and it's not like the cards play any differently whether they have the physical die on it or not unless there is some gameplay aspect I'm not aware of.

Comment: That's true. Then I'd say the locked die places on adventure cards act as a kind of a task that needs a die? Then you'd need to resolve them in order

Comment: The rules don't seem to imply that these die locks are anything like tasks. They seem simply to be a 'all adventures with yellow locks must be eliminated for access to the yellow die again' sort of thing, as if they all had the die sitting on them, or not at all (ie no distinction).